# Why am I getting "return _this.state.data" instead of JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, reactjs

I have a parent component doing an AJAX call to get a JSON object. I've done a few console.log's to make sure that the data is correct in the parent component, but then when I pass through props, I get a value of:

```
ƒ data() {
  return _this.state.data;
}
```

What I've done to this point seems simple enough so I can't find what the issue is.

**Parent Component:**

```
class InfoBox extends Component {
  state = {
    data: []
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.loadDonationsFromServer();
    setInterval(this.loadDonationsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
  };

  loadDonationsFromServer = () => {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments",
      dataType: "json",
      cache: false,
      success: data => {
        this.setState({ data });
      },
      error: (xhr, status, err) => {
        console.error(status, err.toString());
      }
    });
  };

  render = () => {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <h1>Information</h1>
        <InfoList
          data={() => this.state.data}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  };
}

export default DonationBox;
```

**Child Component:**

```
class InfoList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: this.props.data
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.state.data);
    //logs: ƒ data() {
    //         return _this.state.data;
    //      }
  }
  render() {    
    return <div> Placeholder </div>;
  }
}

export default InfoList;
```

I tried using bind in the child component but still got the same thing:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: this.props.data
    };
    this.checkData = this.checkData.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.checkData();
  }

  checkData = () => {
    console.log(this.state.data);
  };
```

Comment: In your parent component, you are declaring a class `InfoBox` but exporting a class `DonationBox` - that's just a typo, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, **yes**, you *should* change the `data` prop that you send to `InfoList` to be `this.state.data` rather than an anonymous function. So: `<InfoList data={this.state.data} />`

But, the main issue is in using `componentDidMount` in the child component, when really **you should be using `componentWillReceiveProps` instead.**

---

### componentDidMount is only called once, and it doesn't wait for your AJAX

The `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook is invoked one time, before the initial `render`.

In your child component, at `componentDidMount` you are trying to log `this.state.data` - but this state is based on what was set in the constructor which was what was passed in as the `data` prop when you first mounted `InfoList`. That was `[]`, because `InfoBox` had yet to receive back data from its Ajax call. To put it another way:

> `InfoList.componentDidMount()` fired before `InfoBox.loadDonationsFromServer()` got back its response. And `InfoList.componentDidMount()` does **not** get fired again.

### componentWillReceiveProps is called whenever props change

Instead, your child component should be using the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle hook. This is invoked every time a component receives new props. Once the parent's state changes (after load donations returns), then it passes new props to the child. In `componentWillReceiveProps`, the child can take these new props and updates his state.

---

I have created a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/1olloowkn7) that shows you through a bunch of log statements what happens when, along with what your props and state look like at various points in the lifecycle. Instead of actually doing an ajax fetch, I'm just doing a 2-second wait to simulate the fetch. In `InfoList.js`, the code for `componentWillReceiveProps` is currently commented out; this way, you can see how things work as they stand. Once you remove the comments and start using `componentWillReceiveProps`, you'll see how they get fixed.

---

#### Additional resources

- This is a [helpful article](https://hackernoon.com/common-pitfall-in-initialising-state-based-on-props-in-react-js-d56795a944aa) that pretty much describes the exact same issue you're facing.
- An excellent quick reference for React lifecycle hooks is the [React Cheat Sheet](https://reactcheatsheet.com/))

Comment: That was it! Your conditional statement in the componentWillReceiveProps function fixed the issue. Thanks, Alvin.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the `data` prop that is being passed in is a function.

**Change**

```
<InfoList data={() => this.state.data} />
```

**to**

```
<InfoList data={this.state.data} />
```

Just a nit, you don't really need the constructor in your child component to define the state. Just define it the way you have in your parent component.

Comment: After removing the anonymous function, it just returns an empty array. Defining the state the same way as in the parent doesn't fix it either. Do you see anything else that might be wrong?

Comment: It looks like your main issue is the empty array, and no longer the `return _this.state.data` function value, since you have changed your code to remove the anonymous function. You may want to update your post (title and code) to reflect more accurately the actual issue you're now facing (with the empty array).